# Sitecore 10.2 XM installation failing on addwebfeatureSSL

Tags: installation, sitecore-install-framework, certificate

`Sitecore 10.2 XM` installation is failing at `step 40` (refer to screenshot).

[image]

I can't clear all certificates and restart because other Sitecore instances are running on the same Azure VM.

Comment: Replace your screenshots with error text for SEO reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed by following steps:

1. Created certificates manually:

New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My -Subject "DO_NOT_TRUST_SitecoreRootCert" -FriendlyName "DO_NOT_TRUST_SitecoreRootCertxm" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeyProtection None -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(10)

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My -Subject "sc102xm.identityserver" -FriendlyName "sc102xm.identityserver" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeyProtection None -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(10) 

New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My -Subject "sc102xm.cm" -FriendlyName "sc102xm.cm" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeyProtection None -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(10)
    
New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My -Subject "sc102xm.cd" -FriendlyName "sc102xm.cd" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeyProtection None -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(10)
```

2. Moved these from personal to trusted root certificates Authorities.
3. Then ran the installation again using these certificate names.